# How to update "Assigned To" field on Knowledge Article Version with Apex?

Tags: knowledge, translation, lightning-knowledge

If I use standard button on Knowledge Article Version (KAV) called **Assign** (api name: `AssignKnowledgeArticleVersion`), it successfully updates the **Assigned To** (`AssignedToId`) field, however, I can't seem to find a way to update that same field without using that button.

I tried using Apex to directly update `AssignedToId` on KAV record, however, that field is not writeable:

> Field is not writeable: Knowledge__kav.AssignedToId

At this point, I would probably give up, but the standard **Assign** button is able to change this field, and Salesforce seems to have exposed a method [`KbManagement.PublishingService.assignDraftTranslationTask(..)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/apex_KbManagement_PublishingService_assignDraftTranslationTask.htm) that can replicate the **Assign** button's behavior.

However, when I tried using the above method the `AssignedToId` still remains the same, even though I'm not getting any errors.

Now, the weirdest part is, when I retrieve the KAV record in workbench using REST API [**/services/data/v45.0/knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/translations/RECORD_ID**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_REST_assign_article_translation.htm), there's an `assigneeId` field in the response that holds the correct value, so something does get updated when I call `KbManagement.PublishingService.assignDraftTranslationTask(..)` method. The problem is that that's not reflected in the `AssignedToId` field, but probably somewhere else in the system.

[image]

Ultimately, what I need to do is to update the `AssignedToId` field on Draft articles via code, so that I can report on that field and use it in List View filters. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to set 'assigneeId' instead of `AssignedToId`?

Comment: I tried it now and got back an error `Variable does not exist: AssigneeId`. Also, if I try to query that field I get back `No such column 'assigneeId' on entity 'Knowledge__kav'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked well for me:

```
KbManagement.PublishingService.assignDraftTranslationTask(
        articleId, assigneeId, instructions, null, false
    );
```

Draft localized article is assigned as expected.
On `force.com` platform `48.0`.